# How to update property binding on view after OnInit? (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am using BehaviorSubject within a service to broadcast selected objects to other components. Everything with the service works including updating the selected object.

My problem is when I run the service within the component I am trying to get the object to, ngOnInit updates the properties on the variable, but it is not updated on my view.

I have tried to use onChanges lifecycle hook, but apparently that doesn't work with objects.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. I know I am missing a few lines of code and that's all.

Here is my Parent Component TypeScript file.

```
  open(content, product: Product) {
    this.modalService2.open(content, { windowClass: 'dark-modal' });
    this.addToCartService.changeProduct(product);
  }
```

Whenever I click "Add to cart" on my view, it triggers the "Open()" method which sends the selected product to the service which is this..

Add To Cart Service Code:

```
@Injectable()
export class AddToCartService {

    product: Product;

    private productSource = new BehaviorSubject<Product>(this.product);
    currentProduct = this.productSource.asObservable();

    constructor() { }

    changeProduct(product: Product){
        this.productSource.next(product);
    }
}
```

Finally the product is updated within the service and it is accessed by the next component which is supposed to display a modal with properties from the updated product..

Add To Cart (Child) Component Typescript file:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.updateBeer();

  }



  updateBeer()
  {
    console.log(this.beerselected);//initially "beerselected" is undefined
    this.addToCartService.currentProduct.subscribe( beer => this.beerselected = beer);
    console.log("from add to cart", this.beerselected);//"beerselected is updated with the object, but the property bindings in the view are still null"
  }
```

initially it is undefined, then the service is called, and the variable beerselected gets its properties updated, but the view is binding to beerselected, however it is still showing undefined.

```
Product Model class:

   export class Product
{
    id: string="beer 1";
    beerName: string="beer 2";
    alcoholPercent: number=5;
    beerType: string="pilser";
    beerPrice: number=10;
    beerAmount: number=120;
    servingSize: number=8;
    beerPicture: string="../assets/";
}
```

Also in case it helps, here is the HTML for Add to cart,

```
   <div class="col-8">
              <h5 class="m-b-0">Beer Name: {{beerselected?.beername}}</h5>
              <ngb-rating [(rate)]="selected" (hover)="hovered=$event" (leave)="hovered=0" [readonly]="readonly"></ngb-rating><br>
              <span><b>Type: </b></span>
              <span class="text-muted">{{beerselected?.beername}}</span> <br>
              <span><b>Alcohol %: </b></span>
              <span class="text-muted">{{beerselected?.beername}}</span> <br>
              <span><b>Description: </b></span>
              <span class="text-muted"></span> <br>
          </div>
```

[image]

Comment: in view why are using ? in object  beerselected?.beername what is purpose of ? in view

Comment: well beerselected is the variable that is being updated when the service is called. There are multiple properties on the "beer" object including beerid, beername, beertype etc.

Comment: i asked there is  question mark sign in object property  why used this question mark sign before bearName

Comment: Otherwise it throws an error that the property is undefined

Comment: perhaps changeDetection could help?

Comment: have you initialized the beerselected ? if not then initialized with new keyword  then check . mostly  when angular throw exception than it don't work properly

Comment: its not change detection issue .. it will update when changeProduct() method will trigger from service otherwise value will not update on ngOnit

Comment: yes I initialized it to be a "Product" which includes all the default properties.They are all undefined on initialization

Comment: could you post a code snippet of the change you want me to try?

Comment: add your model class let me see

Comment: added the product model class

Comment: in model class you just declared the variables but did not initialize the variable i.e beerName: string="beer1"; initialize like this give them some for testing  check this value comes on view before service trigger

Comment: still showing up as undefined

Comment: update your question with update code. where you declared the bearselect object

Comment: updated... please I need a solution soon

Comment: Are you using `OnPush` strategy?

Comment: I think you have to call the change detection strategy explicitly. Simply you can achieve with a setTimeOut
 
this.addToCartService.currentProduct.subscribe( (beer:any) => setInterval(()=>{
        this.beerselected = beer
    }, 10));

Answer (score 0):

Ok the solution I figured out was the way I was binding the data on the front end. Instead of using {{beerselected."whatever property"}} it needed to be {{beerselected.product.property}}

Comment: it solved your problem, did you figure out why this happen. you assigned new beer to beerselected instead of asigned its become property of beerselected,  can you show me  beerselected declaretion ?